# How to update database entries that have oneToMany relations with JPA without creating duplicates

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a class (Material) which has three OneToMany relationships with other classes. Persisting these into the database is no problem and the relation works. Getting the material from the database also works fine. But I have been struggling with updating the data in the database properly. For reference I am working with JPA, Hibernate, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL. My setup is like this:

**Material entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "MATERIAL")
public class Material {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "materialGen", sequenceName = "material_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "materialGen")
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mat_id", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<AltNames> mat_alt_names;
```

**One of the relations:** (I only included one in the example)

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "MAT_ALT_NAMES")
public class AltNames{

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "altGen", sequenceName = "alt_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "altGen")
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "mat_id", nullable = false)
private Material mat_id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
```

**The rest controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "editmaterial/{mat_id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> postEditMaterial(@PathVariable("mat_id") String id, @RequestBody Material material){
    Material returnMaterial = materialService.editMaterial(Long.valueOf(id), material);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(returnMaterial, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**The service class with relevant method:**

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class MaterialService {  

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public Material editMat

erial(long id, Material material) {
        EntityManager nem = createEntityManager();
        Material oldMaterial = nem.find(Material.class, id);
        //Checks if the material is found
        if (oldMaterial == null) {
            log.error("No materials found by id");
        }
        nem.getTransaction().begin();
        oldMaterial.setName(material.getName());
        oldMaterial.setAvg_price(material.getAvg_price());

        for (Location l : material.getMat_location()) {
            l.setMat_id(material);
        }
        for (AltNames a : material.getMat_alt_names()) {
            a.setMat_id(material);
        }
        for (Price p : material.getMat_price()) {
            p.setMat_id(material);
        }

        oldMaterial.setMat_alt_names(material.getMat_alt_names());
        oldMaterial.setMat_location(material.getMat_location());
        oldMaterial.setMat_price(material.getMat_price());

        nem.flush();
        nem.getTransaction().commit();

        nem.close();
        return getMaterialByName(material.getName());
    }

    @Transactional
    public EntityManager createEntityManager(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        EntityManager newEm = emf.createEntityManager();
        return newEm;
    }
```

With any feedback I will update the post to give more relevant information and remove irrelevant code. My problem now is that this code does update the data but also creates a duplicate. I've tried several other methods, including merge, not using getTransaction, not using commit but using merge instead. It either doesn't update the data, misses the data in the oneToMany relations or creates a duplicate. 
As an alternative I wouldn't mind creating a duplicate and deleting the original, but I don't yet know how to delete the original without creating conflict.
Any feedback would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please try to call `nem.getTransaction().begin();` at the beginning of the method, especially before `Material oldMaterial = nem.find(Material.class, id);`?

Comment: Any exceptions reported? You really shouldn't need to begin a transaction if you're using @Transactional.

Comment: There are no exceptions, I just check the database and see there's a duplicate entry as well as the altered original entry. I've removed the @Transactional since it wouldn't work without explicitly beginning a transaction. I've also set the begin transaction at the beginning of the method, problem still exists.